# Mapper or Reducer, where to do more processing?

Tags: mapreduce, processing-efficiency

I have a 6 million line text file with lines up to 32,000 characters long, and I want to 
measure the word-length frequencies.

The simplest method is for the Mapper to create a (word-length, 1) key-value pair for every word and let an 'aggregate' Reducer do the rest of the work.

Would it be more efficient to do some of the aggregation in the mapper?  Where the key-value pair output would be (word-length, frequency_per_line).

The outputs from the mapper would be decreased by an factor of the average amount of words per line.

I know there are many configuration factors involved.  But is there a hard rule saying whether most or the work should be done by the Mapper or the Reducer?

The platform is AWS with a student account, limited to the following configuration.
[image: AWS Cluster - Hardware Configuration]

Comment: I'm no expert, but "do some of the aggregation in the mapper" sounds like defeating the whole map-reduce pattern: effectively, you're doing an intermediate "reduce" step and calling it part of the "map" step. Whether that's a good idea comes down to whether map-reduce is the right pattern for you in the first place.

Comment: Also, you haven't mentioned any particular frameworks/implementations here; are you asking from a completely abstract perspective, or do you have some particular environment you're working in?

Comment: I get 8 mappers and 3 reducers.  To rephrase the question, would it not be more efficient to have the mappers do more of the counting work?  Where the mappers count the frequency for each line, and pass the line totals to the reducers.

Comment: i would recommend that, do the Combiner stuff in MAPPER if your Biz logic permits, which reduce the number of records need to be shuffle and sort between reducer hence increasing the performance. Above approach is optimized approach and used across JOINS in PIG / HIVE

Comment: In this particular problem, you can use a Combiner to aggregate the result in the mapper side. This would result in less number of records being moved from the mapper to the reducer, as a result it saves a lot of network bandwidth utilization. The rule of thumb is wherever possible we should try to minimize the number of records being passed from mapper to reducer.